# Why Mariadb Stops Logging During Connection Problems?

Tags: 18.04, mysql, mariadb

I have faced some connection problems while connecting to a MariaDB server. The connections that I opened where closed anormally. When I checked the log files at /var/log/mysql/mariadb-bin.000xxx I can not see any log which must be logged at the problem time. How can I check what was the problem?

Comment: Usually you would not read the binlogs (binary logs) for that information but the error log in `/var/log/mysql/error.log`

Comment: @Matigo why should I not read binlogs?

Comment: I never said you should not read them. I said that abnormal disconnections are generally not recorded in the binlog, but in the `error.log`. Anomalies are errors, and errors go in `error.log`.

Comment: @Matigo but I cant see any abnormal log in the error.log file for the time when problems occured.

Comment: Exactly how long between connect and abnormal close?  There is a timeout that closes idle connections.  We can discuss further if this seems to be the case.

Comment: @Rick James, o solve that problem. I was using mysql pooling in my application, I changed it to the MariaDB pooling and the problem has not occured yet.